# Is it recommended to install MongoDB on Ubuntu instance on AWS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Shall I install `MongoDB` on the Ubuntu instance in `EC2`(Where else is it supposed to be installed)? I will be using `S3` for storage and link the path in the DB. I am creating a website and want to use Mongo for DB. Its a `MEAN` stack. Will also be installing `NodeJS` on the same instance. Are there any other recommendations for Mongo on `EC2` or `AWS` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: AWS launched [Amazon DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/) in 2019. DocumentDB is a kind of managed MongoDB cluster.

<strike>Amazon doesn't have any managed service for MongoDB, so you have to use one or 3+ EC2 instances to run MongoDB.</strike>

Please remember that the MongoDB performances degrade when the DB cannot be entirely stored in RAM, so you should choose the EC2 instance accordingly (I'd suggest a t2.small or t2.medium at least).

If your EC2 instance doesn't have enough RAM, the Linux Kernel may kill your Mongod process and potentially corrupt your data. Creating a swap partition is **not** the right solution, because MongoDB may burn your EBS credits, and make your instance extremely slow and then unreachable.

For more info about the EBS burst credits: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html#EBSVolumeTypes_gp2

If you want to deploy a MongoDB cluster, please read: [MongoDB on AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/architecture.html)

PS: Are you 100% sure that MongoDB is the right choice? You may choose MySQL or PostgreSQL and then take advantage of the [AWS Managed Relational Database Service (RDS)](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm fairly new to AWS and Mongo too. I want to try my hands on AWS+Mongo. I installed mongo locally and created a MEAN stack app that works perfect. Looking into the EBS credits. Why do you say 1 or 3+ instances? Can I host Mongodb on 1 instance and use 1 more as a failover or replica?

Comment: Hi @Somename, you should not create a MongoDB cluster w/ 2 instances. MongoDB requires 3 nodes to elect the new master node if the current one stops working.
For more info please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/

Comment: Thanks again. Would you recommend Mongodb Atlas? Ofcourse I will get my hands dirty on creating the 3 nodes cluster and play with it; but asking your opinion on Atlas. Would you recommend it and do you thing the prices are reasonable?  Thanks again.

Comment: Managing a MongoDB cluster is a PITA. If you're a dev, you should focus on improving/building your web app instead of dealing with the infrastructure. MongoDB Atlas can be a solution, but I cannot give you more info because I've never tried it.